# Python- How to skip whats been printed when returning?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, I am trying to skip my printed lines and come back to my raw_input. Do I need a loop?

```
class stuff(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "This is text"
        print "This is text"
        print "This is text"
        print "This is text"
        print "This is text"

        action = raw_input("> ")

        if action == "blah"
            print "This is text"
            return 'stuff'
```

When I do this, it repeats all of my printed lines, how do I get it to go back to raw_input?

Comment: How are you actually using this class? It's unclear what "When I do this" refers to.

Comment: I am using if for a game, I have already made my engine and map, but I am having trouble within the class. If that makes sense.

Comment: Console outputs usually do not support this.  Think of the console as a printer, printing a log on paper.

Comment: So, by using this format, python will have to print everything every time?

Comment: Yes.  In order to do what you want to do, you need to use a windowing system or at least a console output device that give you addressable controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an attribute for the class which keeps track of whether you've printed the text before. When you *do* print the text, set the attribute appropriately. For example:

```
class stuff(Scene):
    def __init__(self):
        self.seen_description = False
        #other initialization goes here

    def enter(self):
        print "End Of The Road"
        if not self.seen_description:
            print "You are standing beside a small brick building at the end of a road from the north."
            print "A river flows south."
            print "To the north is open country, and all around is dense forest."
            self.seen_description = True

        action = raw_input("> ")

        if action == "go inside":
            print "You enter the brick building"
            return 'brick building'

x = stuff()
x.enter()
x.enter()
```

Result:

```
End Of The Road
You are standing beside a small brick building at the end of a road from the north.
A river flows south.
To the north is open country, and all around is dense forest.
> wait
End Of The Road
> wait
```

Here, we get an extended description the first time we call `enter`, and it is skipped on all subsequent calls.